# What tolerance do typical components have to wrong-polarity voltages/currents?

Tags: power-supply, components, testing

I've always been a bit hesitant to do continuity tests on populated PCBs, on the basis that if there is no trace connecting the two probes, I will be applying some finite voltage to arbitrary IC pins (quite possibly in the wrong polarity) while leaving others unpowered. Is there a 'safe' voltage/current limit for doing this sort of testing?

Another reason for asking this now is that I've noticed that when the output is supposedly switched off on my cheapo bench power supply, it's actually supplying -50mV with an impedance of ~1Kohm. I would guess that this is some way outside the 'safe' limit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all CMOS data sheets I've read for 3.3V and 5.0V logic show a margin of 0.3 as "safe" -- you'll see a "low input" rating of VDD-0.3, and you'll see a "high input" rating of up to VCC+0.3. I think that 0.3 Volt has something to do with the semiconductor process involved, but I don't know the details.

Also, the current (source impedance) of your multimeter is likely to be so low that it won't supply enough current to fry anything, even if it were shorted. I've never fried anything by measuring with my regular Radio Shack auto-ranging multimeter on a board.

I do have one multimeter, though, bought at Harbor Freight (Chinese import special) that eats batteries when I forget to turn it off, and actually has enough current to light up a red LED when continuity probing it ... I don't use this particular multimeter for anything sensitive :-)

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to say what "typical components" are, but generally, a proper multimeter's continuity function isn't enough to harm most things. A good meter will apply a small voltage through a moderate impedance, so the total power that the meter could deliver to the device under test is very small. Even if the resulting current and voltage is outside of the component's specifications, there isn't enough energy delivered by the meter to harm anything.

My general advice: don't be afraid to poke around with your meter, unless you have specific reason to believe the device is sensitive or expensive. What you gain in knowledge and experience from experimentation is worth much more than the small chance of damage.

Comment: A minor caution: poking around a circuit which is completely unpowered (*and has all caps drained to safe levels*) is pretty safe.  Powered circuits may be another story.  During operation, even a microamp drawn from the wrong node in a low-quiescent-current power-supply circuit may disrupt the output voltage sufficiently to severely damage the circuitry it powers.